# „vor allem“ bei Personen

Tags: word-usage

Ich war gerade versucht, einen Satz wie diesen zu schreiben:

> Ich wünsche der ganzen Familie, vor alle**m** dem Geburtstagskind, ein frohes Fest.

Aber das kam mir komisch vor. Ich stelle mit „vor allem“ ja das Geburtstagskind vor den Rest der Familie, aber „vor allem“ klingt unangemessen sachlich.

Als Alternative bietet sich an:

> Ich wünsche der ganzen Familie, vor alle**n** dem Geburtstagskind, ein frohes Fest.

Das scheint mir richtiger zu sein, aber irgendwie seltsam.

Daher die Fragen:

- Ist es unangemessen, „vor allem“ zu verwenden, wenn es um Menschen geht?
- Ist „vor allen“ eine zulässige Alternative?

Comment: Noch sachlicher bzw. entpersönlichter wären für mich 'notabene', 'beziehungsweise', 'respektive' und ähnliche Formulierungen. Falls dir 'vor allem' zu unpersönlich vorkommt: _..., und heute natürlich besonders dem Geburtstagskind..._  '_Vor allem_' mit Bezug auf Menschen finde ich okay und auch nicht unpersönlich, bei '_vor allen_' bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob es nicht nur artikelartig zu verwenden ist: '_vor allen Anwesenden aber dem Geburtstagskind_; falls es pronominal geht, ist es rar, man sagt nach meinem Empfinden eher '_jn vor allen Leuten loben_' als '_jn vor allen loben_'.

Comment: Deine zwei Alternativen sind identisch. Das war sicher keine Absicht?

Comment: Ich hätte geschrieben: Ich wünsche dem Geburtstagskind und der ganzen Familie ein frohes Fest.

Comment: @tofro Es geht um den Unterschied zwischen "allem" und "allen". Zugegeben, es ist schwer zu sehen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Wortgruppe "vor allem" ist sehr gebräuchlich. Daher fällt es beim normal schnellen Hören oder Lesen überhaupt nicht auf, dass damit die Familie "versachlicht" wird, und niemand wird Anstoß daran nehmen.

"Vor allen" ist hingegen so ungewöhnlich, dass es ins Auge sticht, und dann stellt es die Familie stärker als beabsichtigt in den Hintergrund.